# Show that group ring QG is isomorphic to Q(e3)xQ.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-groups, primitive-roots, group-rings

Let G be a group of order 3 and e3 - primitive root of unity of order 3.
Show that group ring QG is isomorphic to Q(e3)xQ (Carthesian product).

Earlier I have shown that group ring Q(e3)G is isomorphic to 3 copies of Q(e3), but I don't know how to do this part. It seems counterintuitive bcs QG rather looks like only Q(e3), without Q on second carthesian coordinate.

Any hints?

Comment: You have been using this site for a while now, so I suspect that you have already heard that questions and answers should be posted with mathematical expressions [formatted, as is explained here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360).

Comment: On another note, it is strange to me that you decided that "Cartesian" requires an h in the middle.

Comment: Your question has many errors (for instance, Q(e3)G is supposed to be Q(G)).  Could you please make sure that there are no errors in your original question?  I assume that Q is supposed to be $\Bbb Q$ (written as `$\mathbb Q$`), which is to say the rational numbers.

Comment: Yes, Q is rational numbers. Are You certain? Maybe there are errors, but not made by me, I wrote it here just like it is stated.  So, thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $j$ be a primitive third root of $1$. Since $G$ has order $3$, it is cyclic.

I leave you as an exercise to prove the following sequence of isomorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras:

$$\mathbb{Q}[G]\simeq \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^3-1)\simeq \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2+X+1)\times \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X-1)\simeq \mathbb{Q}(j)\times\mathbb{Q}.$$

Comment: It makes me sad when I see such easy solutions and I was not able to think about it that way for 2 days. Thanks, I wish You all the best.